# How to redirect stdout and stderr to different files in DOS?

Tags: batch-file, dos, piping

Lots of questions and answers on putting these in the same file or redirecting to the same place; not a lotta love for putting them in different files.

I want to run my console app:

```
C:\>foo -option >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

...or something along those lines, where normal output goes to `stdout.txt` and error output goes to `stderr.txt`.

Comment: I don't have a Windows/DOS box to test, but what you have (`foo -option >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt`) should work. What happens when you try it?

Comment: it creates the file but doesn't drop error information into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it looks like the above mentioned syntax is indeed correct... in this case, my console app was redirecting everything to standard out which is why nothing showed up in the stderr.txt.